# Persistent learning in pypy

Tags: pypy

I have a python program that executes in about 1s. When executed under pypy it takes about 2s.  However if I change my program from

```
import sys
from code import execute
if __main__:
    execute(sys.argv)
```

to

```
import sys
from code import execute
if __main__:
    for i in range(100):
        print i
        execute(sys.argv)
```

you can really se how pypy is "learning". The first runs takes about 2 seconds, then the executions goes faster and faster to end up taking about 0.15s.

Can I make pypy "remember" its optimization learning, so that the first run takes 0.15. As it looks now I cannot benefit from pypy, since my aplication will run many stand alone executions of the function execute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that's [basically not possible](http://doc.pypy.org/en/latest/faq.html#couldn-t-the-jit-dump-and-reload-already-compiled-machine-code).

What is possible is to get the result you want with workarounds: for example, turn your program into a local "server" which waits for requests (done from executing a 5-lines script), and serves them by doing the job of `execute()`.  It's certainly not the most elegant solution but it lets all the `execute()` be done by the same process, with (after a while) the same speed-ups that you measured.